# How do I add the TSL to my local Keycloak instance?

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, keycloak, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Keycloak instance running locally in version 21. I would like to add a certification (TSL) to go from http://localhost:8081 to https://localhost:8843 to do some access restriction tests.

To do this I have a docker-compose that generates this instance. I tried to mount the key/certificate files on the container created with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) (localhostcert.pem & localhostkey.pem).

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/demo/certs/localhostcert.pem
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/demo/certs/localhostkey.pem
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 8843:8843
    volumes: 
       - type: bind
         source: ./keycloak-restrict-client-auth.jar
         target: /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-restrict-client-auth.jar
       - ./certs:/opt/keycloak/demo/certs
```

The instance launches and works perfectly but only in http://localhost:8081 but not in https://localhost:8843 which returns me an unattainable page.

NB : I am on linux ubuntu 20.04

If anyone has an idea, thanks in advance.